# performance issue with record.set extjs 4.2.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I observed that record.set takes around 500ms to execute. I am working with extjs 4 and I am trying to update values in grid. I tried suspendLayouts() and resumeLayouts() but couldnt really get it to work. Any suggestion on how can I reduce the processing time with record.set()

Comment: I think you're not posting all the relevant information. Are the records you're updating in a grid?

Comment: Hey sorry, I have edited my question

Comment: I suspect there is another problem. This operation should not take as much time.

Comment: record.endEdit() takes a lot of time...DO you have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Post please the code that would show what you are doing. That operation just cannot take that long. How many fields you update? How many records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to suspend events on the store so it doesn't try and individually update the rows.

```
store.suspendEvents();
store.each(function(rec) {
    rec.set('foo', 'bar');
});
store.resumeEvents();
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added grid.suspendLayout=true before calling the function where it performs record.set and record.endEdit() operation and added grid.suspendLayout=false after returning from that function.